# Hide tabbar and extended bottom of view to the bottom edges in iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Hiding tabbar leaves space below safe area in iPhone X and newer devices. How do I extend my view (yellow) to the bottom edges? I've read various solutions provided elsewhere but none are suitable for me as I've to present same view controller with or without tababar based on a condition.

Is there any simple solution?

Or do I've to pin the bottom edge of view to the bottom of device? If this is the case how?

For hiding I'm using this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

[image: Tababar]

Answer (score 0):

```
let controller = UIViewController()
controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with hiding tabbar which is already hidden. I've already tried this by checking Hide Bottom Bar on Push in storyboard which is same as you have written. Tab bar is hiding, this is not the issue. There is space below tabbar which I want to hide by extending the yellow view to the screen's bottom edge.